# How to get the TreeView from inside the ItemTemplate class?

Tags: wpf, treeview, itemtemplate

I have a TreeView class like so, which has my own class "EntryPanel" as an ItemTemplate:

```
<TreeView x:Class="PowerNote.MyEntriesView"             
         xmlns:local="clr-namespace:PowerNote"
         DataContext="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}"
         ItemsSource = "{Binding viewStudents}">
    <TreeView.ItemTemplate>
        <HierarchicalDataTemplate ItemsSource="{Binding Children}">
            <local:EntryPanel/>
        </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
    </TreeView.ItemTemplate>
</TreeView>
```

In my EntryPanel.xaml.cs code, I would like to access the TreeView. I tried Parent, and TemplateParent, but neither would work. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

Try Doing in this way to Find the Parent.

```
public static T TryFindParent<T>(this DependencyObject child)
where T : DependencyObject
{
   //get parent item
   DependencyObject parentObject = GetParentObject(child);

   //we've reached the end of the tree
   if (parentObject == null) return null;

   //check if the parent matches the type we're looking for
   T parent = parentObject as T;
   if (parent != null)
   {
      return parent;
   }
   else
   {
    //use recursion to proceed with next level
    return TryFindParent<T>(parentObject);
   }
 }
```

This one will find the parent object.

```
 public static DependencyObject GetParentObject(this DependencyObject child)
 {
   if (child == null) return null;

   //handle content elements separately
   ContentElement contentElement = child as ContentElement;
    if (contentElement != null)
    {
      DependencyObject parent = ContentOperations.GetParent(contentElement);
        if (parent != null) return parent;

         FrameworkContentElement fce = contentElement as FrameworkContentElement;
        return fce != null ? fce.Parent : null;
     }

   //also try searching for parent in framework elements (such as DockPanel, etc)
   FrameworkElement frameworkElement = child as FrameworkElement;
   if (frameworkElement != null)
   {
      DependencyObject parent = frameworkElement.Parent;
      if (parent != null) return parent;
   }

   //if it's not a ContentElement/FrameworkElement, rely on VisualTreeHelper
   return VisualTreeHelper.GetParent(child);
}
```

This snippet works with arbitrary dependency objects that are of Type Visual or Visual3D. So let’s say you need a reference to the Window that hosts a given Button control somewhere, all you need is this:

```
Button myButton = ...
Window parentWindow = UIHelper.TryFindParent<Window>(myButton);
```

The above TryFindParent method also makes it easy to get an item at a given position. The method below performs a hit test based on a given position. If hit testing does not return the requested item (e.g. a clicked CheckBox on a tree, while you are keen on the TreeViewItem that hosts the CheckBox), the procedure delegates the lookup to TryFindParent.

This comes in very handy for mouse-related events if you just need to now what’s under your mouse pointer:

```
  public static T TryFindFromPoint<T>(UIElement reference, Point point)
    where T:DependencyObject
  {
     DependencyObject element = reference.InputHitTest(point)
                           as DependencyObject;
     if (element == null) return null;
     else if (element is T) return (T)element;
     else return TryFindParent<T>(element);
  }
```

[Reference](http://www.hardcodet.net/2008/02/find-wpf-parent)

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: @NathanTuggy Yes you are correct. I am not sure do this helped the PO but still I am posting the content of the link here. Thanks for the hands up.